# Передача массива в качестве параметров и его вывод

Tags: php

Пробую вот такой вод код:

```
<?php
class Month
{
    public $name;
    public $daysNumber;
    public $monthNumber;

    public function __constructor($name, $daysNumber,$monthNumber)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->daysNumber = $daysNumber;
        $this->monthNumber = $monthNumber;
    }
}

class Season
{
    public $name;

    public $months;

    public function __constructor($name, $months)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        foreach ($months as $month)
         array_push( $this->months , $month);
    }
}

$winter=[ new Month("December",30,12), new Month("Jan",31,1), new Month("Feb",30, 2)];
$spring =  [new Month("March",30,3), new Month("April",30,4), new Month("May",30,5)];
$summer = [new Month("June",30,6), new Month("July",30,7), new Month("August",30,8)];
$autumn = [new Month("September",30,9), new Month("October",30,10),new Month("November",30,11)];

$seasons = [new Season("Winter", $winter), new Season("Spring", $spring), new Season("Summer", $summer), new Season("Autumn", $autumn)];

echo $seasons[0]->months[0];

foreach ($seasons as $season) {
    echo $season->name;
    foreach ($season->months as $month)
        echo $month;
}
```

У меня есть месяцы и сезоны. Всё это реализовано в двух классах, пытаюсь вывести через foreach но нет, всякие фичи из шарпов тут не работают. Выводит ошибку

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 41
```

Comment: Надо угадать где строка 41?

Comment: @u_mulder о, точно.  "foreach ($season->months as $month)
        echo $month;". Вот она.

Comment: Конструктор это `__construct`.

Comment: @u_mulder а Season это класс. Поясните детальней, пожалуйста, я не понимаю.

Comment: `__construct` а не `__constructOR`.

Comment: @u_mulder ох, я даун.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно заменить все `echo` на `var_dump()` *(для визуального контроля значений)*, а так же явно объявить массив для функции `array_push()`:

```
<?php

class Month
{
    public $name;
    public $daysNumber;
    public $monthNumber;

    public function __construct($name, $daysNumber,$monthNumber)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->daysNumber = $daysNumber;
        $this->monthNumber = $monthNumber;
    }
}

class Season
{
    public $name;

    public $months = [];

    public function __construct($name, $months)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        foreach ($months as $month)
            array_push($this->months, $month);
    }
}

$winter=[ new Month("December",30,12), new Month("Jan",31,1), new Month("Feb",30, 2)];
$spring =  [new Month("March",30,3), new Month("April",30,4), new Month("May",30,5)];
$summer = [new Month("June",30,6), new Month("July",30,7), new Month("August",30,8)];
$autumn = [new Month("September",30,9), new Month("October",30,10),new Month("November",30,11)];

$seasons = [new Season("Winter", $winter), new Season("Spring", $spring), new Season("Summer", $summer), new Season("Autumn", $autumn)];

var_dump($seasons[0]->months[0]);

foreach ($seasons as $season) {
    echo $season->name;

    foreach ($season->months as $month) {
        var_dump($month);
    }
}
```